# Bokeh server, simple html page

Tags: python, web-applications, server, tornado, bokeh

I have a large data feed that I need to compute on my machine and share with other users that will be updated roughly every 5 mins. The easier solution would be a bokeh server on my machine that they can connect to to view the data.

When I try and run the bokeh server, I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Failed to push document: AttributeError("'PropertyValueList' object has no attribute '_owners'",)
```

I think it is something about how I am getting it to run, I start with setting the server up:

```
python -m bokeh serve
```

then I compile and run the following example from the bokeh website:

http://docs.bokeh.org/en/0.11.1/docs/user_guide/server.html#userguide-server

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import pi

from bokeh.client import push_session
from bokeh.driving import cosine
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc

x = np.linspace(0, 4*pi, 80)
y = np.sin(x)

p = figure()
r1 = p.line([0, 4*pi], [-1, 1], color="firebrick")
r2 = p.line(x, y, color="navy", line_width=4)

# open a session to keep our local document in sync with server
session = push_session(curdoc())

@cosine(w=0.03)
def update(step):
    r2.data_source.data["y"] = y * step
    r2.glyph.line_alpha = 1 - 0.8 * abs(step)

curdoc().add_periodic_callback(update, 50)

session.show() # open the document in a browser

session.loop_until_closed() # run forever
```